# Program outputs correct value, but crashes at the end

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i;

    int a[14];
    int b[14];

    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {

        cin >> a[i];

        b[i]=(a[i] % 37);

    };

    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {

        cout << b[i] << "\n";

    };

    return 0;


}
```

My program inputs 15 values and outputs every of them modulo 37. The results are perfect, but for some reason I can't figure out, the program crashes at the end ("program stopped working").

Comment: 14 and 15 are different numbers.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<15; i++)` loops 15 times but the array has 14 elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most programming languages array indexing starts at 0. This means that index "13" in your code is last.
You need to replace `i < 15` to `i < 14`:

```
for (i=0; i < 14; i++)
```

`0` is first element and `length - 1` - last

Comment: The OP seems to know that indexing starts at 0, since she says `for (i=0`.

Answer (score 2):

`int a[14];` means that there are 14 elements.
But since iteration starts with `0`, you'll try to access the 15th element, which does not exist. Change your loops to `< 14`